# User defined type (UDT) behavior in VBA 6.0

Tags: arrays, excel, cluster-analysis, vba

I'm triying to create my own data type which is supposed to contain an array and a long data type; I have defined it as public type:

```
Public Type MyData
Cluster() As Variant
Centroid As Long
End Type
```

And I have created a sub to use it:

```
 Sub Mycluster()
Dim Cong As MyData
Dim i As Long
 i = 1
 ReDim Cong.Cluster(i)
 For i = 1 To 10
 Cong.Cluster(i) = Rnd() * 9 + 1
   ReDim Preserve Cong.Cluster(i)
 Next i
  Cong.Centroid = Application.Average(Cong.Cluster)
  Debug.Print Cong.Centroid
End Sub
```

but when debbuging Iget this error:

[image]

Some help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redimming after trying to add more elements, hence the error. But since you know the size upfront, don't think you need do that at all.

```
Sub Mycluster()

Dim Cong As MyData
Dim i As Long

ReDim Cong.Cluster(1 To 10)

For i = 1 To 10
    Cong.Cluster(i) = Rnd() * 9 + 1
    'ReDim Preserve Cong.Cluster(i)
Next i

Cong.Centroid = Application.Average(Cong.Cluster)

Debug.Print Cong.Centroid

End Sub
```